# Bind reverse DNS server configuration issue

Tags: dns, bind, reverse-dns

I have a reverse DNS server setup with Bind.
This is what my zone file looks like,

```
[root@PCPDNS01 named]# cat 127.195.203.arpa
@       IN      SOA     ns1.premier.com.au. root.bpoint.com.au. (
                                20140530        ;serial
                                14400           ;refresh
                                3600            ;retry
                                604800          ;expire
                                10800           ;minimum
                                )

127.195.203.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      ns1.premier.com.au.
127.195.203.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      ns2.premier.com.au.

35                              IN      PTR     smtp2.bpoint.com.au
17                              IN      PTR     smtp2.bpoint.com.au

130                             IN      PTR     mail.greenpowered.com.au
[root@PCPDNS01 named]#
```

When I do a reverse DNS check on http://www.dnsinspect.com/

I get the following,

[image]

However I don't want to have 127.195.203.in-addr.arpa in there. how do i resolve this?

many thanks,

--Archie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[root@PCPDNS01 named]# cat 127.195.203.arpa
@       IN      SOA     ns1.premier.com.au. root.bpoint.com.au. (
                                20140530        ;serial
                                14400           ;refresh
                                3600            ;retry
                                604800          ;expire
                                10800           ;minimum
                                )

                                IN      NS      ns1.premier.com.au.
                                IN      NS      ns2.premier.com.au.

35                              IN      PTR     smtp2.bpoint.com.au.
17                              IN      PTR     smtp2.bpoint.com.au.

130                             IN      PTR     mail.greenpowered.com.au
```

Above configuration fixed this issue.

a "." at the end of the ns1.premier.com.au

:)